# Rails App not Reloading Code in Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, puma

I've been working on a Rails recently and for testing purposes I needed to switch from the default WEBrick server to a server with multithreading support. I chose to use Puma, which is easily configured via a gem and one line in the development.rb file.

**Development.rb:**

```
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

# Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

# Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
# with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true

config.threadsafe!
```

The only line I needed to add was the final "config.threadsafe!" For reference here is the Gemfile as well.

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"   
  gem 'puma'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'cocaine', '= 0.3.2' 
gem 'streamio-ffmpeg'

gem 'cancan'
gem 'formtastic'

gem 'jbuilder'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

# To use debugger
#gem 'debugger'

gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
```

This ended up serving the purpose I needed it for and the app functions correctly. The problem is that anytime I make a change to anything (JS, CSS, Controllers, Views, etc.) the changes won't show up until I restart the server.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? More importantly, what can I do to change it so that a server restart isn't necessary to have changes show up?

Answer (score 1):

By adding `config.threadsafe!` to your development.rb file, you are disabling automatic code reloading. See the implementation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L102):

```
  # Enable threaded mode. Allows concurrent requests to controller actions and
  # multiple database connections. Also disables automatic dependency loading
  # after boot, and disables reloading code on every request, as these are
  # fundamentally incompatible with thread safety.
  def threadsafe!
    self.preload_frameworks = true
    self.cache_classes = true
    self.dependency_loading = false
    self.allow_concurrency = true
    self
  end
```

You should remove `config.threadsafe!` from development.rb.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was config.threadsafe! that was causing the issue. I need it to properly test key functionality of my app though. Is it possible to configure the threadsafe! method so that it doesn't disable reloading code?

Comment: not as far as I know, can you be more specific about what you need to test?

Comment: Upon making a successful transaction, the create/update action in two of my controllers references an API to create a JSONP string which is then saved into a dynamically created file. Because of the API call the server needs to use an additional thread. Otherwise, the server will hang and eventually cause a time-out error. This is core functionality of the app so I need to have multi-threading enabled for general testing purposes.

Comment: see this blog post: http://railsware.com/blog/2012/12/19/fixing-multithreading-for-rails-in-development-mode/

Comment: Interesting. I'm not quite sure how to go about monkeypatching ActiveRecord but it seems like a good place to start. I'll check it out on Monday.